# case statement in where clause with in values oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case, oracle-apex

I am working on Oracle Apex application. I have a simple select query which is working fine but now I want to do if/else or case statement in that query.

so query is below

```
select value d,
       id r
  from dhm_lov_data
 where lov_id = 103
   and nvl(isdeleted,0) = 0
   and parentid_1 =:p21_typeid
 order by d
```

I want to change this query to add a condition on `:P21_TYPEID` value.
E.g. if `:P21_TYPEID` value is 1 then in where clause it should be `PARENTID_1 in (10,11)`
otherwise `PARENTID_1 = :P21_TYPEID`.

I tried to put it in case statement but it didn't work. Below is query I am trying to make work using a case statement

```
SELECT  VALUE d, id r FROM DHM_LOV_DATA WHERE LOV_ID= 103 and nvl(ISDELETED,0) = 0  
and 
case when :P21_TYPEID = 848 then PARENTID_1 in (287,288)
    else PARENTID_1 = :P21_TYPEID  end;
order by d
```

Answer (score 3):

A `case` expression returns a value, not a condition you could just add to your `where` clause. But you could emulate this behavior with some boolean operators:

```
SELECT   value d, id r 
FROM     dhm_lov_data
WHERE    lov_id = 103 AND
         NVL(isselected, 0) = 0 AND
         (:P21_TYPEID = 848 AND parentid_1 IN (287,288) OR
          :P21_TYPEID = parentid_1)
ORDER BY d
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *ugly* example, perhaps?

```
select  value d, id r 
from dhm_lov_data 
where lov_id = 103 
  and nvl(isdeleted, 0) = 0  
  and parentid_1 in (select :p21_typeid from dual
                     where :p21_typeid <> 848
                     union
                     select val from (select 287 val from dual 
                                      union
                                      select 288 val from dual
                                     )
                     where :p21_typeid = 848
                    )
```